# Scale a sprite in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a sprite in as3 code, I want to enter its height to resize it, how can I scale the width accordingly?

```
sprite.height = 200;
sprite.width = ??
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scale properties are updated when you set the width/height, so you can use them to scale the other dimension:

```
sprite.height = 200;
sprite.scaleX = sprite.scaleY;
```

Easier and less error prone than tracking/updating the aspect ratio on your own.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to scale a sprite, why not use use scale methods?

```
sprite.scaleX = 2;
sprite.scaleY = 2;
```

Otherwise, you will need to apply a ratio, such as width / height.

Say your sprite was width: 150, height: 100.  That means width is 1.5 times height.

```
// calculate ratio of scale factor
var ratio:Number = sprite.width / sprite.height; // 1.5

// apply ratio your sprite's original dimensions:
sprite.height = 200;
sprite.width = sprite.height * ratio; // 300
```

This could also be accomplished using a Matrix transform.